# How to combine three char to one

Tags: c, arrays, strcat

I had three char inside the array , which contain X1 X2 and X3

```
char array[3]={X1,X2,X3}
```

I want to combine three data which inside the array to one char

```
strcat(array[0]," ");
strcat(array[0],array[1]);
strcat(array[0]," ");
strcat(array[0],array[2]);

printf("%s",array[0])
```

I expect to get the result like this "X1 X2 X3"

Comment: So you have three _characters_ and want to create a string of them? Or do you have three _strings_ and want to combine them into a single string?

Comment: You want to combine the characters in an array to a string where each character is separated by a space? Or something else?

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean you want to concatenate 3 chars to a make one string.

Use `sprintf` with a sufficient array:

```
char str[6];
char array[3] = {'l', 'o', 'l'};

// write
sprintf(str, "%c %c %c", array[0], array[1], array[2]);

// print
printf(str);
```

Comment: Care to explain the fault in my answer?

Comment: You didn't check `malloc`'s return value. This is very bad practice, even for a "toy" example", since the OP seems to be a beginner.

Comment: This is C. `void*` can be promoted to `char*` with no cast needed. Bleh, removed the `malloc` example. I see what you mean. It can fail to allocate the memory. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

you will need one more byte to have a null terminator.

```
char array[4] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' };
printf( "%s\n", array );
```

will give your abc

Comment: or just `char array[] = "abc";`

Comment: Your result string does not contain spaces as asked by OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it that way. `array` is only 3 bytes long, so you can't have the string "a b c", which is 5+1 = 6 bytes long in it. And, of course, you can't call `strcat(array[0], ...` since `array[0]` is a single char, not a `char *`.

I'm not sure what you are looking for, but if you are given X1, X2 and X3 and want them in a string separated by spaces, you can do that :

```
void chars2str(char x1, char x2, char x3, char* dest) {
    sprintf(dest, "%c %c %c", x1, x2, x3);
}
```

Of course, the `dest` argument must be big enough or something very nasty might happen.

```
char mystr[6];

char2str('a', 'b', 'c', mystr);  /* Now mystr contains "a b c" */
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you're using `strcat` is incorrect. `array[0]` is a `char`, which means it can hold only a single letter. It cannot hold X1 *along with* a " " or X2. Create another sufficiently big char array and then you can `strcat` to that.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *join(char *result, const char array[], size_t size, const char sep){
    size_t i,len=0;
    for(i=0;i<size;++i){
        len+=sprintf(result+len, "%c", array[i]);
        if(i < size - 1)
            len+=sprintf(result+len, "%c", sep);
    }
    return result;
}

int main(void){
    const char array[] = { 'x', 'y', 'z'};
    char result[6];

    join(result, array, sizeof(array)/sizeof(char), ' ');
    printf("%s", result);//"x y z"
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert each individual char to a string, then concatenate them.

e.g.

```
    char c = 'c';
    char d = 'd';
    string s1(1, c);
    string s2(1, c);
    string cd = s1 + s2;
```